# GTK+ widget is resizing itself within a Paned

Tags: gtk, vala

I have GTK+ (Vala) app that has Main Window with a ScrolledWindow with a HPaned with two VTE Terminals in it. In some cases terminal itselfs resizes the paned. I don't want to allow terminal resize it, I only want to allow user to move with splitter and resize it.

I dont set any properties:

```
var sw1 = new Gtk.ScrolledWindow(null, null);
var sw2 = new Gtk.ScrolledWindow(null, null);
var paned = new Gtk.HPaned();
paned.pack1(sw1, true, true);
paned.pack2(sw2, true, true);
var main_box = new Gtk.VBox(false, 0);
main_box.pack_start(this.menubar, false);
main_box.pack_start(paned);
this.add(main_box);
```

How to do that? Why the Terminal (ScrolledWindow) is trying to resize? How can I prevent this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: I have even tried to set_position manually, but it seems GTK+ always recalculate the position according to the "best" sizes. I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set

```
sw1.set_size_request(-1, 300);
sw2.set_size_request(-1, 300);
```

so it wont "scretch" while there are less lines.